# Можно ли царить ПО (некоему пространству)?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> **По** всей **Римской империи царит** смятение, а сам Рим измучен голодом и поражён чумой.

Comment: Выделение болдом делает фразу ещё более неприличной. Это сделано специально?

Comment: Я выделяю шрифтом то, к чему хочу привлечь внимание. А что неприличного было в предложении, что усугубилось болдом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**царить**
3. *перен.* иметь преимущественное ***распространение*** где-либо, в чём-либо; господствовать, преобладать.

Большой толковый словарь:
СМЯТЕНИЕ, -я; ср.
1. Сильное волнение, возбуждение, тревога.
Душевное смятение. Смятение чувств. Мною овладело смятение. Убежать в смятении.
2. Паника, растерянность, переполох.
Смятение в городе. **Везде царит смятение.** Поднялось всеобщее смятение.

***Смятение и террор царят по всей стране.***
[**Ц. Кохави-Рейни. Королева в раковине**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=VcqyAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT351&lpg=PT351&dq=%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%20%20%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D0%BE&source=bl&ots=onW5esV7c3&sig=_wyA06DBpWJsrOkXtc130UUi3Bk&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3gp2dqbLYAhWCHpoKHWEsCIkQ6AEIRzAG#v=onepage&q=%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%20%20%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D0%BE&f=false)

Смятение царит (где?) везде, по всей стране, по всей Римской империи.
[Царит = распространяется (по определению), и по территории (пространству) государства — в том числе.]

"По всей Римской империи царит смятение..." — думаю, ТАК можно сказать.

Answer (score 2):

По-моему, корректно "**по всей империи прошло** смятение" или "**во всей империи царит** смятение". Царит - это статическое состояние, а "ПО" - оттенок движения  в пространстве ( распространения).

Но с другой стороны, здесь всё-таки смятение - уже движение. Может, автор так использовал этот предлог, чтоб усилить слово смятение? Можно же сказать "по всему городу звучит..."(распространяется).

Answer (score 1):

**По всей Римской империи царит смятение.**

Из словаря: **Везде царит смятение.**
https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/es/144504/%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Можно сказать: повсюду царит смятение.

**Предлог ПО** —  3. Употр. при обозначении места, пространства, **в пределах, в границах** которого происходит действие, движение.

**Предлог В** — внутри империи, предлог ПО —  **во всех землях империи**, то есть в каждой провинции.